# Analog audio out when starting from /etc/rc.local

Tags: python-3, alsa, vlc, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I am working on a python program that I am having some issues with. When the user presses a button a video starts playing. I need the audio to come from the analog jack. It works perfectly when I run it from the terminal or in thonny.

The problem started when I tried to autorun it. I set it up to autorun with /etc/rc.local. It starts correctly, but there is no audio from the VLC player. I am using `os.system("amixer sset 'Master' 100%")` to set the volume and in my log I get the error `amixer: Unable to find simple control 'Master',0`. I tried adding `os.system("amixer scontrols")` to get a little more information, and I got the following: `Simple mixer control 'HDMI',0` "Master" isn't mentioned there like it is when I run that command from a terminal.

So what is different here? Why is HDMI audio output my only option when starting from rc.local? I have tried starting with and without sudo and that made no difference.

Comment: Because the audio out is just like video out -- there's only one for the system, and things that run *in the background* (such as those started from `rc.local`) don't automatically get to access it.  That said, I don't have the solution for this (but I am sure there is one).

Comment: I'm sure you know that `rc.local` has been deprecated. I assume "**autorun**" means "start at boot"?? If so, maybe try another method for auto-starting - a `systemd` unit, or `cron`?

Comment: I did try cron, and it behaved exactly the same way. I am going to try another way tomorrow and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't understand why the other methods weren't working, but I solved the problem by starting the script from ~/.bashrc. It works perfectly now.

Comment: `.bashrc` is **NOT** intended to run scripts.

It is run each time a non-login interactive shell is started and is used to configure the shell.